# ubuntu 12.04 File Permissions or owner were insecure

Tags: permissions, network-manager

Let me explain a little bit about what i am trying to do, i am trying to manage Network Manager files via a non root user and i keep getting the error message that says:

```
keyfile: updating /etc/NetworkManagere/system-connections/zzssid
keyfile: error: File Permissions (100660) or owner (1000) were insecure
```

and then the machine won't connect to wifi, but if the root user creates the file and places it in the system-connections folder then the wifi works right away.

Any suggestions or feedback on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `man NetworkManager.conf`:

```
keyfile
        plugin  is  the  generic  plugin  that  supports all 
the connection types and capabilities that NetworkManager has. 
It writes files out in a .ini-style format in 
/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections. For security, it will 
ignore  files that  are  readable or writeable by any user or 
group other than root since private keys and passphrases may be stored
in plaintext inside the file.
```

In your case the owner of the file `/etc/NetworkManagere/system-connections/zzssid` is the user having UID `1000` and the permission was set as `660`, so expectedly it was not working. You need to set the owner and group as `root` with only `root` having the read-write permission. Here is an example:

```
$ ls -l /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/

-rw------- 1 root root 324 Feb 18 20:36 Test-WiFi
-rw------- 1 root root 315 Apr 11 01:14 FooBar-WiFi
```

Comment: Yes that is what my problem is, i need to be able to set the SSID from a frontend code such as php etc...so i want this file to be owned by somebody other than root as i cannot run my application as root, right not what i am doing as a workaround is that copying the file to the system-connections folder as non root and at reboot time setting those files to root

Comment: but somehow i am not convinced its a good idea, let me know if there is a better idea

Comment: @mandm: So, your goal is different..i wonder it would be a safe option to write the file as a normal user and then change the permission later to meet the need..also you should not make the `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/` directory writeable by others....you would be better to ask what you want as a new question..my opinion is "don't do this"....also as my answer solved your original question, select this as accepted by clicking the tick-mark on teh left of my answer so that this issue can be marked as solved..